# Integrate user paypal account with react native, as a payment method

Tags: react-native, paypal

What are the process for let integrate user paypal account with your react native app (with paypal login page), as a payment method.

NB : I underline the point "as a payment method", so we use this for later payment (and not for a immediate payment).

An tutorial url is also welcome.

(Excuse my bad english)

Comment: Was this issue solved?